# Locking a file during load/require

Tags: ruby, file, locking

1. During a file is `load`-ed/`require`-d, is the file locked from writing?
2. If not, how can I exclusively lock the file from writing during `load`/`require`?

Probably, [`File#flock`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#method-i-flock) should be used if so, but I don't know the answer to the first question, and also how to combine it with `load`/`require`.

Comment: The set of system calls made when you require a file is ruby shows ruby does not acquire a lock on the file, you can verify this with `strace ruby -r set -e 'Set.new'` on any linux system with `strace` installed, so what you are suggesting is probably the only way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is opened the only protection you have is if the file is deleted, technically unlinked from the filesystem and orphaned, you can still read the contents. Closing the file forfeits any access to it from that point on. That's how it works on POSIX type systems in any case, Windows *may* be different.

There's nothing to prevent another process from over-writing part of the file or truncating it while your process is trying to do its thing.

Remember `File#flock` is simply a polite way of requesting a lock and unless the other process that's about to manipulate the file is polite and checks you have no guarantees about the state of your file. Processes are free to ignore that and mangle your file without warning.

The only way to be sure nobody touches your file is to copy it to a private `/tmp` directory, test that the thing copied correctly, and read it in from there. That's an extremely paranoid thing to do so I'd hope you have a compelling reason before going down that road.

If you can control all the processes that access your file and make them well-behaved citizens and use a consistent locking mechanism for the file you'll probably be fine. If that's not the case you may want to have a master process that grants access to the files on an exclusive basis using some kind of IPC signalling.